# Javascript game controls

Tags: javascript, controls

This is my first attempt at a JavaScript game.
I am trying to make a javascript game with a yellow block that you can control with the `w` `a` `s` `d` keys. The blue square is supposed to be an enemy that makes you loose if you hit it. I will add more features later. The problem: the game works fine until you release one of the buttons. How can I prevent the player block from flying away when you release the controller buttons?

I also can't make the buttons work when I enable the `w` `a` `s` `d` keys as controllers, but I do not consider that as a major problem at this point. Even so, I will be quite happy if some one know how to fix it.

```js
var myGamePiece;
var myFi;

function startGame() {
  myGameArea.start();
  myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "rgba(200,200,0,0.5)", 10, 175);
  //blueGamePiece = new component(20, 20, "blue", 300, 110);
  myFi = new component(15, 15, "blue", 300, 120);
}
var myGameArea = {
  canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
  start: function() {
    this.canvas.width = 680;
    this.canvas.height = 420;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
      myGameArea.keys = (myGameArea.keys || []);
      myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
    })
    window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
      myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
    })
  }, // I don't get why the comma is so important and what it does!

  clear: function() {
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  },

  stop: function() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
  this.gamearea = myGameArea;
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.speedX = 0;
  this.speedY = 0;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.update = function() {
    ctx = myGameArea.context;
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  }
  this.newPos = function() {
      this.x += this.speedX;
      this.y += this.speedY;
    },
    this.crashWith = function(enemy) {
      var myleft = this.x;
      var myright = this.x + (this.width);
      var mytop = this.y;
      var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
      var fileft = enemy.x;
      var firight = enemy.x + (enemy.width);
      var fitop = enemy.y;
      var fibottom = enemy.y + (enemy.height);
      var crash = true;
      if ((mybottom < fitop) || (mytop > fibottom) || (myright < fileft) || (myleft > firight)) {
        crash = false;
      }
      return crash;
    }
}

function updateGameArea() {
  if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myFi)) {
    myGameArea.stop();
  } else {
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGamePiece.speedX += myGamePiece.speedX;
    myGamePiece.speedY += myGamePiece.speedY;
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[65]) {
      myGamePiece.speedX = -1;
    }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[68]) {
      myGamePiece.speedX = 1;
    }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[87]) {
      myGamePiece.speedY = -1;
    }
    if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[83]) {
      myGamePiece.speedY = 1;
    }
    myGamePiece.newPos();
    //blueGamePiece.x -=1;
    //blueGamePiece.y +=2;
    //blueGamePiece.update();
    myGamePiece.update();
    myFi.update();
  }
}

function moveup() {
  myGamePiece.speedY = 1;
}

function movedown() {
  myGamePiece.speedY = 1;
}

function moveleft() {
  myGamePiece.speedX = 1;
}

function moveright() {
  myGamePiece.speedX = 1;
}

function clearmove() {
  myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
  myGamePiece.speedY = 0;
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
div {
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
button {
  background-color: black;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button onmousedown="moveup()" onmouseup="clearmove()">UP</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button onmousedown="moveleft()" onmouseup="clearmove()">LEFT</button>
  <button onmousedown="moveright()" onmouseup="clearmove()">RIGHT</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button onmousedown="movedown()" onmouseup="clearmove()">DOWN</button>
</div>

<p>I have created a game area!</p>
<p>Then I created a component to my game! I is a yellow square!</p>
<p>I continued to add frames and movement</p>
<p>After I had added movement, I could finally add controllers</p>
<p>First I added the buttons that was controlled by the mouse,
  <br>then I added the keystroke controllers for the w,s,a,d keys.</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR: A jsFiddle to demonstrate** https://jsfiddle.net/tty7y1gr/3/

The first thing you asked is how to get the player to stop moving. Try changing these lines:

```
myGamePiece.speedY = 1;
```

to this:

```
myGamePiece.speedY += 1;
```

Also, you are not setting the movement down, left, and right properly: there are no negative values. Try this:

```
function moveup() {
  myGamePiece.speedY -= 1;
}

function movedown() {
  myGamePiece.speedY += 1;
}

function moveleft() {
  myGamePiece.speedX -= 1;
}

function moveright() {
  myGamePiece.speedX += 1;
}
```

And another thing is you have this bit of code here:

```
myGamePiece.speedX += myGamePiece.speedX;
myGamePiece.speedY += myGamePiece.speedY;
```

This will make the game piece have staggered, sporadic movement because the speed will keep adding on to it self until the game piece gets pretty much exponentially faster. Unless this is intentional, to smooth out the movement, get rid of these two lines.

Next question I saw in there was the `w` `a` `s` `d` keys. Try something like this:
Place this in your GameArea():

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {            
        myGameArea.keys = (myGameArea.keys || []);
        myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});

window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
        myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});
```

and this where you are creating your player "Controller" (or movement)

```
myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
myGamePiece.speedY = 0;
if (myGameArea.keys && (myGameArea.keys[37] || myGameArea.keys[65])) {
    myGamePiece.speedX = -1;
  }
  if (myGameArea.keys && (myGameArea.keys[39] || myGameArea.keys[68])) {
    myGamePiece.speedX = 1;
  }
  if (myGameArea.keys && (myGameArea.keys[38] || myGameArea.keys[87])) {
    myGamePiece.speedY = -1;
  }
  if (myGameArea.keys && (myGameArea.keys[40] || myGameArea.keys[83])) {
    myGamePiece.speedY = 1;
  }
}
```

(this is for arrow keys as well)

But this will make your button movement stop working. To prevent that, you have to make the gameupdate() not always have your game piece's speed set to 0. So, put a check in there that will set a variable to release the speed of your game piece when you click the buttons on the screen, and then set it back when you stop pressing those buttons. Something like this:

Outside of myGameArea.update():

```
var buttonMove = false;
```

Wrap the setting of game piece's speed:

```
if (!buttonMove) {
        myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
        myGamePiece.speedY = 0;
}
```

Inside of myGameArea.update():

```
function moveup() {
  buttonMove = true;
  myGamePiece.speedY -= 1;
}

function movedown() {
buttonMove = true;
  myGamePiece.speedY += 1;
}

function moveleft() {
buttonMove = true;
  myGamePiece.speedX -= 1;
}

function moveright() {
buttonMove = true;
  myGamePiece.speedX += 1;
}

function clearmove() {
buttonMove = false;
  myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
  myGamePiece.speedY = 0;
}
```

I saw a comment in your code about why you need a comma there. You need it there because you are creating a JavaScript object whose properties are separated by commas. So `myGameArea` looks like this:

```
var myGameArea = {
  canvas: "value",
  start: "value",    
  clear: "value",    
  stop: "value"
}
```

Except it has fancy "values" in place, some are functions, some are elements, etc.

And one last thing, to "clamp" your player down so they cannot go outside of the canvas, you need to set their bounds with something like this after your "Controller" but before you update the position:

```
Number.prototype.clamp = function(min, max) {
    return Math.min(Math.max(this, min), max);
  };

  myGamePiece.x = myGamePiece.x.clamp(0, myGameArea.canvas.width - myGamePiece.width);
  myGamePiece.y = myGamePiece.y.clamp(0, myGameArea.canvas.height - myGamePiece.height);
```

a jsFiddle to demonstrate:

https://jsfiddle.net/tty7y1gr/3/